# Graficar 2 variables con grafico de barras

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data, plot

Estoy empezando en el mundo del análisis de datos con Python, y estoy intentando llevar a cabo un par de proyectos de mi trabajo a modo de practica y también por utilidad.

En uno de ellos necesito (o mas bien quiero), graficar la distribución de las ventas a lo largo del año.

Para ello extraje una tabla que tiene 3 columnas, una es la fecha, otra es el numero de documento fiscal y la otra puede ser el precio de lo vendió, el volumen y peso, cantidad de productos etc, el caso es que es algo así, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se  fijan hay 2 fechas y 9 vetas, se hicieron 4 ventas el dia 1 y 5 ventas el dia 2.

Mi idea es agrupar las vetas hechas en cada fecha para graficarlas y ver la distribuicion a lo largo del año.

Hasta ahora se como graficar una variable y ver su distribución en un histograma, un scatter plot o boxplot, pero todo el tema de agrupar los valores y graficar uno contra otro no se como hacerlo.

Si alguno tiene mas experiencia que (lo cual no dudo porque mi experiencia es 0 xD) y pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Nota: Hasta ahora he ido aprendiendo a trabajar con Pandas y Matplotlib, agradecería (si es que es posible) las respuestas sean en función de esta librería ya que me gustaría conocerla bien a profundidad antes de pasar a otros conocimientos, aunque igual recibiré muy bien cualquier idea.

les dejo lo que llevo de codigo y el grafico resultado:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    
    
    mainpath= "Desktop/CML"
    filename= "Libro1.xlsx"
    fullpath= mainpath + "/" + filename
    
    data = pd.read_excel(fullpath)
    
    data.head()
    
    
    data.plot(kind="bar",x = "venta" ,y = "valor")
```

[image: En este grafico no se logra apreciar las etiquetas del eje x, por lo tanto no se si estoy graficando adecuadamente, ademas me parece un tipo de grafico muy pobre]

En este grafico no se logra apreciar las etiquetas del eje x, por lo tanto no se si estoy graficando adecuadamente, ademas me parece un tipo de grafico muy pobre

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Haz intentado algo, pon lo que haz intentado para ayudarte mejor e irte guiando

Comment: Hola @christian actuaice mi pregunta para mostrar el codigo y el resultado que obtuve. ademas te comento que me recomendaron en otro sitio que trabajara con plotly pero no se nada al respecto, sabes donde podria conseguir algo de informacion sobre esto?

Comment: Primero escoge algunos datos como prueba y muestra los en el gráfico así sabrás si están bien, en cuanto a agrupar los datos haz intentado con un ciclo ```for```? Recorriendo los datos y añadiéndoles a una lista?,  yo te recomiendo que utilices *matplotlib* pero este no es un sitio de recomendaciones, aquí tienes la documentación de [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/)

Comment: @christian gracias, voy a probar lo que me dices.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder agrupar, puedes usar el comando:

```
grouped_data = data.groupby('fecha')
```

Luego calculas el total de ventas en cada grupo:

```
sales_by_date = grouped_data['valor'].sum()
```

Y luego muestras un gráfico de barras de la distribución de las ventas a lo largo del año:

**sales_by_date.plot(kind='bar')**

En esa última linea puedes cambiar por el tipo de gráfico que desees.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
# Crea un DataFrame de ejemplo con ventas en diferentes fechas
data = pd.DataFrame({'fecha': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02'],
                     'valor': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})

# Genera números aleatorios entre 100 y 1000
random_values = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=3)

# Agrega más fechas con ventas al DataFrame
data = data.append({'fecha': '2022-01-03', 'valor': random_values[0]}, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append({'fecha': '2022-01-04', 'valor': random_values[1]}, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append({'fecha': '2022-01-05', 'valor': random_values[2]}, ignore_index=True)

# Agrupa las ventas por fecha
grouped_data = data.groupby('fecha')

# Calcula el total de ventas en cada grupo
sales_by_date = grouped_data['valor'].sum()

# Muestra un gráfico de dispersión con una escala de colores según el valor
sales_by_date.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]